# How to check if case class parameter has value or not in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, case-class

I have a case class `QueryParams`as follows:

```
case class QueryParams(
limit: Option[Integer] = None,
refresh: Option[Boolean] = None,
organisationalUnit: Option[String] = None)
```

These values `limit`,`refresh`,`organisationalUnit` are actually passed as query parameters in request url for play application.
I need to write a code to check if request URL contains any value for `organisationalUnit` and if yes I need to throw error .If no, I need to proceed with further operations.
Can anyone help me here

Comment: What have you tried so far? For instance, googling it perhaps?
Looking at `Option` scaladoc?

Answer (score 0):

`Option`s are quite good for this kind of thing:

```
val params: QueryParams = ???

params.organizationalUnit.foreach(_ => throw new Exception("your error message"))
```

In this way you'll throw only if `organizationalUnit` is defined. You can also express it as follows:

```
for (_ <- params.organizationalUnit) {
  throw new Exception("your error message")
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
if (params.organizationalUnit.isDefined) {
  throw new Exception("your error message")
}
```

The latter is probably the most readable, even though it may not be recognized as very idiomatic according to certain coding styles.

Comment: This is a nice thorough answer. I'll just add that I doubt anyone would have much of an issue with the last solution. In fact I definitely prefer it. Usually the main thing to avoid is `.get`, not any of the other methods of `Option`. Though it sounds like the asker might just have some more complex further work that should involve a for-comprehension or something.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from stefanobaghino is good but I prefer pattern matching for such cases:

```
params.organisationalUnit match {
  case Some(_) => // processing
  case _ => //logging
}
```

If you need other values you can match the whole instance

```
params match {
  case QueryParams(Some(limit), Some(refresh), Some(organisationalUnit)) =>
  case QueryParams(mayBeLimit, mayBeRefresh, Some(organisationalUnit)) =>
  case _ =>
}
```